# Xamarin App Program: "How can i make login form to be first page when app start open"?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, authentication, html, login-control

i wanna ask about xamarin app in VS 2010
i've built app xamarin, and the question is
"how can i make login page to be first page when i start open my app"?
thanks before.

Comment: Can you add more context to what type of application and what have you done so far and what is that you are stuck with etc?  There is lot of samples of login in Xamarin.

Comment: just simple login,
and how can i make my login page to be first page when i run the app?
that's all

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [MainPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Application.MainPage/) property of App.cs.

```
public App ()
{
      MainPage = new LoginPage ();
}
```

or if you need Navigation, you can wrap the login page in a navigation page

```
public App ()
{
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage ());
}
```

Your `LoginPage` can be a cs file or xaml.cs file based on how you build your View (UI).

Read about simple login implementation - [Hierarchical Navigation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Views_and_Layouts)

Please look into [Xamarin.Forms Quickstart](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/) and [Xamarin.Forms Multiscreen Quickstart](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms-multiscreen/quickstart/)

Also would be useful to read about [Navigation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Navigation), [Views and Layouts](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Views_and_Layouts)